# When splitting a string into multiple columns using REPLACE function gives an unexpected result which results in the sql error?. How to to fix it?

Tags: sql

I have attached my table with the data.  Using the data in 'JOBNUMBER' column I have to get the values before and after the '_' and write that value in 'CONTRACTNUMBER'. For exammple '2_25_000'  JOBNUMBER ,[My table details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Y2i.png)I have to get '25' as CONTRACTNUMBER. I use the below query

```
SELECT 
    BD.BTCHID,BD.JOBNUMBER as JOBNUMBER,
    LEFT(replace(BD.JOBNUMBER, substring(BD.JOBNUMEBR, 1, charindex('_', BD.JOBNUMEBR)), ''),charindex('_', replace(BD.JOBNUMBER,substring(BD.JOBNUMBER, 1, charindex('_', BD.JOBNUMBER)), '')) -1 )AS CONTRACTNUMBER ,
    Substring(BD.JOBNUMBER, 1, charindex('_', BD.JOBNUMBER)) AS String1,
    Replace(BD.JOBNUMBER, substring(BD.JOBNUMBER, 1, charindex('_', BD.JOBNUMBER)), '') as String2,
    Charindex('_', replace(BD.JOBNUMBER, substring(BD.JOBNUMBER, 1, charindex('_', BD.JOBNUMBER)), ''))AS CHARINDEX
 FROM  [dbo].[BATCH_DETAILS] BD;
```

I get all the records processed except for the JOBNUMBER '8_8_000'. Whenever the values (in between the 2 underscores) are same 'LEFT' function throws error '*Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.'*.

If you look at the last column 'CHARINDEX'  values across JOBNUMBER (8_8_000) it should be '2' instead is gives '0  and for 'String2' it give value '000' instead of '8_000'. How to get the exact value of 'CONTRACTNUMBER' when the first and second values are same in the 'JOBNUMBER' column as mentioned above.

Can someone help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific functions used in the above code.)